# iterator for map - problem with searching

Tags: c++

hello i got an iterator running on a multimap ,my multimap includes two fields the first 1 is the key value which is a string Lastname and the second 1 is the data which is a pointer to an object called Employee.
in my program i need to be able to find an element inside my map using iterator (cause i am trying to find the data by its ID and not by the key value).
i want to have some sort of indicator that will tell me if the element i am looking for is inside my map or not.
thanks in advance.
and this is my Find code :

```
MultiMap::iterator iterator;
iterator=m_municipalityMap.begin();
bool flag = false;
while(!(flag) && iterator != m_municipalityMap.end())
{   
    if(strcmp(iterator->second->GetId() , id) == 0)
    {   
        flag=true;
        break;
    }
    iterator++;
}
if (flag==false)
    cout << "could not find Employee"<<endl;

return iterator;
```

what i need to know if there is a way to know if the iterator stands on nothing like comparing to NULL on pointers

Comment: Just a small comment: use `++iterator` instead of `iterator++`.

Comment: Some comments: 1:as Kirill pointed out, this solution is not scalable. 2: use std::string if possible. 3: don't check for flag if you use break. 3: prefer for over while.  I don't see any obvious error in you're code, so check by printing out Id and GetId() in your loop.

Comment: i use the flag cause i need to indicate myself if i found the item or not

Comment: (sorry for late response): you also check it in your while-loop, together with breaking when found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need two keys in the container you could try [Boost Multi-index Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Another solution is to create two maps, each one with own key, and keep your data in each by (smart) pointers.

Comment: do you know if linux compiler contain this libary ?

Comment: Almost all modern Linux distributives contains Boost.

Comment: the thing is i got all of my progrem sorted and i got a little problem with this iterator probably there should be a easy solution for my problem i rather not try boost yet by thank anyway for your comment

Comment: Updated my answer with non-Boost solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the std::find_if algorithm with a suitable predicate that will handle finding 
your Employee based on the ID.

This is an adaption of an example found in "The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference" by Nicolai M. Josuttis, Addison-Wesley, 1999:

```
class value_id_equals 
{
private:
    string m_id;
 public:
    // constructor (initialize id to compare with)
     value_id_equals (string id)
      : m_id(id) { }
    // comparison
    bool operator() (pair<string, Employee*> elem) 
    {
        return (!strcmp(elem.second->GetID(), m_id.c_str()));
    }
};

...
pos = find_if(your_map.begin(),your_map.end(),    // linear complexity
              value_id_equals(theID));
```

Comment: `return (!strcmp(elem.second->GetID(), m_id.c_str()));` should be written as `return elem.second->GetID() == m_id;`

Comment: It COULD be written like that. Or even using the compare function of the std::string. But do you know that GetID() will return a std::string? How do you know that? I used the OP's context, that is he was using strcmp, which meant that his GetID returned a char*. The question wasn't about strcmp versus std::string compare.